# C# Interface: Handling instance classes using generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, asp.net-core-webapi

We are trying to build a web api request to handle different type of business actions in a common endpoint. We have got a parent model class which holds common fields, and each business type has its own class inheriting from base model class. Controller input type will be the base class and client must specify the type being sent in the request (designated enum value for each type, not the fully qualified type name). We have created a custom de-serialiser to convert the received object to actual type based on the specified type.

Like model classes, we have got base interface inherited by each business type. Since the actions are same across different business types and only the input and output types of each action varies, we defined a generic base interface holding all the actions. Each business specific class inherits interface by specifying relevant model type during inheritance.

**Problem trying to solve:**

> I know the model type through custom de-serialiser. Based on this type
> I must get the instance of class inheriting the interface for the
> identified type and call the method of that service. How to achieve
> this?

Written below method but getting runtime exception for invalid casting

```
private static ITransactionService<Transaction> GetServiceInstance(Transaction transaction)
{
    return transaction switch
    {
        Commitment => (ITransactionService<Transaction>)new CommitmentService(),
        Drawdown => (ITransactionService<Transaction>)new DrawdownService(),
        _ => null
    };
}
```

Below is the complete code structure for reference:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
public class Commitment : Transaction
{
    public string Investor { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
public class Drawdown : Transaction
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
public interface ITransactionService<T> where T : Transaction
{
    T Create(T transaction);
    T Update(T transaction);
    T Apporve(T transaction);
}
public class CommitmentService : ITransactionService<Commitment>
{
    public Commitment Apporve(Commitment transaction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Commitment Create(Commitment transaction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Commitment Update(Commitment transaction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class DrawdownService : ITransactionService<Drawdown>
{
    public Drawdown Apporve(Drawdown transaction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Drawdown Create(Drawdown transaction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Drawdown Update(Drawdown transaction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**The exception I am getting:**

[image]

Basically we are trying to reduce number of classes and endpoints need to be created for each type.

Comment: `CommitmentService` is not `ITransactionService<Transaction>` it is `ITransactionService<Commitment>`. They are not the same

Comment: Option 1) use more generics eg `GetServiceInstance<T>`. [in your `Main` example, the caller knows the type, but could use reflection instead] Option 2) introduce a non-generic interface eg `ITransactionService<T> : ITransactionService`.

Comment: At the core of this - it would not be correct to pass any `Transaction` type into `ITransactionService<Commitment>`, for example `new Drawdown()` into `CommitmentService`. So your interface abstractions and your intentions are not in sync.

Comment: Thank you @Chetan, yes types are not same. And that is my questions as well how to address this scenario.

Comment: @KarthikPonnusamy in order to be able to cast to `ITransactionService<Transaction>` your services must implement the `ITransactionService<Transaction>` interface and not any of more specific interfaces.

Inside the implementation you can use pattern matching, to check / cast parameters to desired types.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyLakeman, trying to avoid reflection. RE option 2, I need to have the method signatures in the non-generic interface with a common type for input and out. That again needs to be implemented in every class right?

Comment: You could implement the non-generic interface methods on an `abstract class BaseService<T> : ITransactionService<T>` with runtime casts between `T` & `Transaction`.

Comment: @Nenad, true we should not allow any transaction type into CommitmentService. I think with type being specified in the generic interface, CommitmentService will accept only Commitment and not Drawdown.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, sorry I could not follow what you mean. Could you please give more information RE abstract class implementation for this?

Comment: @KarthikPonnusamy - if those interfaces should not allow swapping of types (I agree), than your question how to define generic interface for both services is a bit out of place. You don't want those 2 to be swappable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) problem, `ITransactionService<Commitment>` can't be cast to `ITransactionService<Transaction>`. Some variance problems can be solved by adding `in` or `out` [keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces).

But in general all variance problems can be solved with either more generics. Forcing the caller to either know the actual type, or invoke the methods via reflection;

```cs
private static ITransactionService<T> GetServiceInstance<T>(T transaction)
```

Or more types with less generics. Adding methods that allow the caller to access features without needing to know the actual type;

```cs
public interface ITransactionService
{
    Transaction Create(Transaction transaction);
    Transaction Update(Transaction transaction);
    Transaction Apporve(Transaction transaction);
}
public interface ITransactionService<T> : ITransactionService where T : Transaction
{
    T Create(T transaction);
    T Update(T transaction);
    T Apporve(T transaction);
}
public abstract class BaseService<T> : ITransactionService<T> where T : Transaction
{
    Transaction ITransactionService.Apporve(Transaction transaction)
        => Apporve((T)transaction);
    public abstract T Apporve(T transaction);

    Transaction ITransactionService.Create(Transaction transaction)
        => Create((T)transaction);
    public abstract T Create(T transaction);

    Transaction ITransactionService.Update(Transaction transaction)
        => Update((T)transaction);
    public abstract T Update(T transaction);
}
```

Now every `ITransactionService<T>` has a known base type, `ITransactionService` that you can cast.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyLakeman. This has worked for me in the sample code. Now I will try the same with my project code.